# Check box disabling

Tags: ms-access-2007

I am doing a project of managing a database. Here I have to make a checklist wherein a  check box in an MS-Access 2007 form employees have to check in so that their responses get registered in the database. But, after a certain time, that is the deadline field, I want to disable the check box so that no more checking in is allowed. I am completely new to VBA. I would be very thankful if someone could help me out or guide me through the programming part of this.

Answer (score 1):

In your VBA that will control this checkbox, there's a few options you can use.

```
MyCheckBox.Enabled = False
MyCheckBox.Locked = True
MyCheckBox.Visible = False
```

The first one will disable the control and grey it out.
The second one will lock out any changes, but it stays the same color.
The third one will completely hide it.

Hope this helps. Good luck.